# "aws: command not found" when used in a script invoked by a Snap

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to take screenshots and have them uploaded to my S3 bucket.

I tried to use both ksnip and ScreenCloud (installed as snaps), and I have a similar problem with both.

I configure them to run a bash script I wrote in order to uploaded the screenshot.

The bash script uploads the file using the `aws` command.

It works fine when I run it manually, but doesn't work when executed by ksnip or ScreenCloud.

I see this error in the syslog: "aws: command not found".

This is not specific to `aws`. I also get a similar error when i try to use the `uuidgen` utility.

I tried to use the full path: `/usr/local/bin/aws`, but it also doesn't work. I get "No such file or directory" (note that I verified that this command DOES work when invoked manually in the shell).

I guess that the script run by both programs doesn't have access to the general environment. I'm not sure if it's a configuration issue, or an inherent limitation of snaps.

What is the right (or at least working :) ) way to allow my script to access `aws`?

Comment: Snaps run in self-isolation, and need specific kinds of resources and connections to run system files.  USUALLY, snaps are not exposed to the general system at large's installed items and scripts, becuase they're exposed only to the items linked into it with the snap permissions or as part of the Ubuntu Core snap.  Is your script running in the command line directly or as a snap?  Is `aws` a snap?

Comment: `aws` is not a snap. My script is invoked by the snap. Both ksnip and ScreenCloud have an option to invoke a custom script when taking a screenshot. So I guess the script inherits their permissions. I'm actually happy to learn that snaps' access to my system is so limited, but then how can I achieve anything that requires external programs? Is there a way to somehow tell the system to give this specific script extended permissions even though it's invoked by a snap?

Comment: Where do all these programs sit?  Typically, you shouldn't be doing this if it refers to things outside the snap as it breaks the idea of 'sandboxes' and isolation from the system to an extent.  Closest you could probably get would be adding the `system-files` interface to the relevant snap for the relevant directories that you and your script are going to use with read access, but that could be very tricky getting it to work proper.

Comment: The snaps are under `~/snap/<program>`. `aws` binary is in `/usr/local/bin/aws`. It also has configuration files in `~/.aws/*`. Sounds like making it work with snaps will be too complicated... thank you for the explanations and suggestions!

Comment: I meant the other programs you're having issues with.  To work with just /usr/local/bin/aws and your home directory for files, you'd have to add a few 'interfaces' with configuration lines for your snap to access directories.  See https://snapcraft.io/docs/system-files-interface and that you may have to give the snap in question the system-files permission to read/use `/usr/local/bin/aws` and `/home/$USER/.aws/*` (where you replace `$USER` with your username)

Comment: In ksnip's case the Snap is only allowing execution of application that were allowed when building the snap, I believe currently it's only ftp and curl. Using ksnip outside a snap (AppImage for example) should allow you to run any other program.

Comment: thanks @DamirPorobic. i preferred not to install ksnip outside a snap... anyway i have already got around this issue in a different way (without ksnip) :)